# Why does GMap.NET colors are opposite?

Tags: wpf, gmap.net

I have very strange problem.
The color of any map provider given to GMap.NET  the colors are opposite.
did anyone encounter this issue?

I have a side project with same parameters and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind.

It turns out that gmap.NegativeMode was set to true.

It fixed it.

thanks anyway.